# FFMPEG works from command line but not PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I have a strange situation that has just happend. FFMPEG is no longer executing from PHP but will from the command line.

Here is exactly what the command is:

```
ffmpeg -i ../../uploads/ee78d5deb564901626067cc0008456ed.mp3 -ab 96k -y ../../uploads/mp3/ee78d5deb564901626067cc0008456ed_6203688.mp3
```

How it is executed in the PHP script:

```
if(! exec("ffmpeg -i ".$target_path."".$hash_filename.".".$path_extension." -ab 96k -y ".$target_path."mp3/".$hash_filename."_".$session_ID.".mp3")){
    echo 'ffmpeg failed';
}
```

This command did work but not longer does. I have recently updated plesk but I highly doubt that has affected this. The only thing that I think could affect it that I have recently done is have the file upload go to a subdomain. So the directory where the file is located and stored in the command is in a directory outside the document root. However, the `move_uploaded_file` function works and I have altered the `open_basedir` in PHP ini to the webspace root.

Comment: You can try to output the error with $error = array(); exec("your command here", $error); var_dump($error);

Answer (score 0):

tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log

and lets us know what you see there...Adjust for your platform...

this is for lamp (opensuse )

Answer (score 0):

You can try the system() command. It will return you the response from server

```
system("ffmpeg -i ".$target_path."".$hash_filename.".".$path_extension." -ab 96k -y ".$target_path."mp3/".$hash_filename."_".$session_ID.".mp3")
```

if the ffmpeg is not supported with current version of the php it will return you the error.

OR

you can modify your command to get ffmpeg with proper path. In my case it works like below code

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ".$target_path."".$hash_filename.".".$path_extension." -ab 96k -y ".$target_path."mp3/".$hash_filename."_".$session_ID.".mp3"))
```